# Oracle query result is not giving the result

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have the following two tables

table A

```
     Name Location Group Value
     July   AAA    A    1
     Aug    BBB    B    2
     Sep    CCC    C    3
     Oct    DDD    D    4
     Nov    EEE    E    5
```

table AA

```
 Name Location Group Value1
     July   AAA    A    6
     Aug    BBB    B    7
     Jan    CCC    C    8
     Oct    DDD    D    9
     Nov    FFF    F    10
```

I want the following result

```
Name Location Group Value Value1
 July   AAA    A       1    6
 Aug    BBB    B       2    7
 Jan    CCC    C            8
 Sep    CCC    C       3    
 Oct    DDD    D       4    9
 Nov    EEE    E       5    
 Nov    FFF    F            10
```

so far I have used the following query but i am not able to get the result..

```
SELECT A.Name, A.Location, A.Gruppo, A.value, AA.value1
FROM A
Full Outer Join AA
ON A.LOCATION=AA.LOCATION
and
A.GRUPPO=AA.GRUPPO
and 
A.name = AA.NAME
```

the result from the query is the following

```
 Name Location Gruppo value value 1
    July    AAA    A       1    6
    Aug     BBB    B       2    7
                                8
    Oct     DDD    D       4    9
                               10
    Sep     CCC    C       3    
    Nov     EEE    E       5
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: What result do you get with that query? If you get an error, what does it say?

Comment: Your query should return your expected result. If not or you get error you should show it in your question for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might select 3 times, one with inner, and twice with left joins with exclusions. Then union them all into one result set:

```
SELECT A.Name, A.Location, A.Gruppo, A.Value, AA.Value1
FROM A
inner join AA
    ON  A.Location = AA.Location
    and A.Gruppo = AA.Gruppo
    and A.Name = AA.Name
union all
SELECT A.Name, A.Location, A.Gruppo, A.Value, AA.Value1
FROM A
left outer join AA
    ON  A.Location = AA.Location
    and A.Gruppo = AA.Gruppo
    and A.Name = AA.Name
where Value1 is null
union all
SELECT AA.Name, AA.Location, AA.Gruppo, A.Value, AA.Value1
FROM AA
left outer join A
    ON  A.Location = AA.Location
    and A.Gruppo = AA.Gruppo
    and A.Name = AA.Name
where Value is null
```

Comment: Why do so much work? The OP's solution was much better than this, it only needed a small modification.

Comment: I have provided a solution that I know works. Add your recommendation as an answer, so everybody learns a new thing.

Comment: The right answer has already been offered by another respondent.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're not getting the result you're after is because you haven't told the query to select whichever column isn't null for the columns in the join condition.

For example, if the row appears in both A and AA (or just in A), then `a.name` won't be null. However, if the row only appears in AA, then `a.name` is going to be null. In that instance you want it to display `aa.name`, which you can do with COALESCE (or NVL):

```
WITH a AS (SELECT 'July' NAME, 'AAA' LOCATION, 'A' "GROUP", 1 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Aug' NAME, 'BBB' LOCATION, 'B' "GROUP", 2 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Sep' NAME, 'CCC' LOCATION, 'C' "GROUP", 3 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Oct' NAME, 'DDD' LOCATION, 'D' "GROUP", 4 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Nov' NAME, 'EEE' LOCATION, 'E' "GROUP", 5 VALUE FROM dual),
    aa AS (SELECT 'July' NAME, 'AAA' LOCATION, 'A' "GROUP", 6 VALUE1 FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Aug' NAME, 'BBB' LOCATION, 'B' "GROUP", 7 VALUE1 FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Jan' NAME, 'CCC' LOCATION, 'C' "GROUP", 8 VALUE1 FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Oct' NAME, 'DDD' LOCATION, 'D' "GROUP", 9 VALUE1 FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Nov' NAME, 'FFF' LOCATION, 'F' "GROUP", 10 VALUE1 FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables a and aa with data in them. See the SQL below:
SELECT coalesce(A.Name, aa.name) NAME,
       coalesce(A.Location, aa.location) LOCATION,
       COALESCE(A."GROUP", AA."GROUP") "GROUP",
       A.value,
       AA.value1
FROM   A
       Full Outer Join AA
         ON A.LOCATION = AA.LOCATION
            AND A."GROUP" = AA."GROUP"
            and A.name = AA.NAME;

NAME LOCATION GROUP      VALUE     VALUE1
---- -------- ----- ---------- ----------
July AAA      A              1          6
Aug  BBB      B              2          7
Jan  CCC      C                         8
Oct  DDD      D              4          9
Nov  FFF      F                        10
Sep  CCC      C              3 
Nov  EEE      E              5
```